# Create uniqe ID for table and apply it to data with duplicates

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, duplicates, identifier

I am importing an Excel sheet into SQL Server.  It has sales data with client names, no unique client ID in the Excel.  I need to create a client ID and assign it to all the rows.  Of course there are multiple rows for some clients so they must receive the correct ID (already generated).

I am doing this work in SSIS, is there a node that can create a unique ID when necessary or apply an already created ID when the same client is being processed?

I could also do it with a SQL script in a execute script node.  Same task... create a unique id for the clients in the table and apply it to the whole table knowing that there are multiple rows for some clients.

Comment: Nothing OOB. You're looking to implement that logic in a Script Component (transformation). You might have to sort the data first, depends on your logic

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, one option uses `dense_rank()`. The following expression gives you a unique, incrementing id for each client:

```
dense_rank() over(order by client_name) as client_id
```

If you want a TSQL `update` statement that sets column `client_id`:

```
with cte as (
    select client_id, dense_rank() over(order by client_name) as new_client_id
    from mytable
)
update cte set client_id = new_client_id
```